# Iteratively declare variables based on string?

Tags: python, variables, iteration

Not sure if this has been asked before or not.  Its a bit of an odd question, so I'll go ahead and fire away.

I've got some variable (or rather constant) definitions:

```
# Constants

# Colors
RED="RED"
ORANGE="ORANGE"
YELLOW="YELLOW"
GREEN="GREEN"
CYAN="CYAN"
BLUE="BLUE"
MAGENTA="MAGENTA"
# Modes
PANIC="PANIC"
SOLID="SOLID"
BREATHING="BREATHING"
# Special sub-modes (for panic)
BLINKING="BLINKING"

# Declare them
SOLID_RED="{}_{}".format(SOLID,RED)
SOLID_BLUE="{}_{}".format(SOLID,BLUE)
SOLID_MAGENTA="{}_{}".format(SOLID,MAGENTA)
## ..
BREATHING_RED="{}_{}".format(BREATHING,RED)
BREATHING_BLUE="{}_{}".format(BREATHING,BLUE)
BREATHING_MAGENTA="{}_{}".format(BREATHING,MAGENTA)
## ..
PANIC_RED="{}_{}".format(PANIC,RED)
PANIC_BLUE="{}_{}".format(PANIC,BLUE)
PANIC_MAGENTA="{}_{}".format(PANIC,MAGENTA)
## ..
PANIC_BLINKING="{}_{}".format(PANIC,BLINKING)
```

I got a lot of definitions!  Instead of having to type them all out like this, would there be a way for me to just construct all these constants into existence as strings only using the definitions BEFORE `# declare them` , or by using, say, a dictionary?

The format I'd need for such a iterative construction is:  `MODE_COLOR` naming convention.

I require that this answer works using Python 2.7.  As I have some dependent 2.7 APIs included.

Comment: Not sure how this is Python 2.7 specific.

Comment: Raspberry Pi - python 2.7 library, and using dependent py2.7 APIs.  Irrelevant comment, there, buddy.

Comment: Your code runs on both Python 2 and Python 3. What it's going to be run on is irrelevant with respect to your question.

Comment: Python 3 has additional syntax in question.  If you actually looked over stack overflow, sir, you'd see that solutions are provided for both versions.  Because the syntax and method support is inherently different.

Comment: "If you actually looked over stack overflow" -- I've been using StackOverflow for 6 years.

Comment: Have a more keen eye, then.  ;)

I appreciate solutions for both versions of python, but this one happens to be a request that is 2.7-specific.

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding about what "2.7 specific" means... It means "This question (i.e., behavior) only applies to Python 2.7 and does not apply to Python 3". It does _not_ mean "I want this to work on Python 2.7". If you want it to work on Python 2.7, you should say that.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant.  People are awfully specific when it comes to specifying very stipulatively a limitation, like as you say "I only wish this to work for Python 2.7".  So I will edit that.  Sorry for the confusion, if any, that it may cause people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using `itertools.combinations` and `locals()`:

```
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint

# Colors
RED="RED"
ORANGE="ORANGE"
YELLOW="YELLOW"
GREEN="GREEN"
CYAN="CYAN"
BLUE="BLUE"
MAGENTA="MAGENTA"
# Modes
PANIC="PANIC"
SOLID="SOLID"
BREATHING="BREATHING"
# Special sub-modes (for panic)
BLINKING="BLINKING"

v_consts = {k:v for k, v in locals().items() if k.isupper()}
combs = combinations(v_consts.values(), 2)
d_consts = {'%s_%s' % k: '%s_%s' % k for k  in combs}
pprint(d_consts)

# Edit:
# If you want to add the created variables in Python's scope
# You can do something like this
globals().update(d_consts)
print SOLID_BLINKING, type(SOLID_BLINKING)
```

Output:

```
{'BLINKING_CYAN': 'BLINKING_CYAN',
 'BLINKING_MAGENTA': 'BLINKING_MAGENTA',
 'BLINKING_ORANGE': 'BLINKING_ORANGE',
 'BLINKING_PANIC': 'BLINKING_PANIC',
 'BLINKING_RED': 'BLINKING_RED',
  ...
 'YELLOW_MAGENTA': 'YELLOW_MAGENTA',
 'YELLOW_ORANGE': 'YELLOW_ORANGE',
 'YELLOW_PANIC': 'YELLOW_PANIC',
 'YELLOW_RED': 'YELLOW_RED'}
 SOLID_BLINKING <type 'str'>
```

Comment: Heh, `locals` is pretty cute.

Comment: @erip I'm little lazy to write the consts again lol so using `locals()` will save me some time.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the best answer, simple 4-liner, and it preserves case.  But would this start throwing things declared above it in, as well?

Comment: @RobertSmith, sorry, english is my third language i didn't get your question. can you explain more what you're saying ? thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're checking if the locals being looped through are all uppercase before adding them.  ( ``if k.isupper()``)  I see.  OK wow yes solution makes perfect sense now.

I was asking if you had some code above that, would that loop begin to add anything else you'd declared?  But I see thats not the case, because you check to be sure its only adding an all uppercase string only.

Comment: @RobertSmith, See my last update. I've added how you can add those created variables in Python's scope in order to use them by they variable names without using the created dict itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary as the container to store the variables.  Just list all of the colors and modes in lists, and then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
colors_list = ['red', 'blue']
modes_list = ['panic', 'solid']
color_modes = {k1 + '_' + k2: k1.upper() + '_' + k2.upper()
               for k1 in colors_list for k2 in modes_list}
>>> color_modes
{'blue_panic': 'BLUE_PANIC',
 'blue_solid': 'BLUE_SOLID',
 'red_panic': 'RED_PANIC',
 'red_solid': 'RED_SOLID'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is emitting a bit of a code smell.

The way I might approach this is by using a dictionary and a cross product. Here's a minified example:

```
from itertools import product

A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = ['d', 'e', 'f']

AB = {"{0} {1}".format(a, b): "{0}_{1}".format(a, b) for a, b in product(A, B)}

print(AB)
```

You can apply this to your colors and modifiers and access the colors by name:

```
colors['Magenta Solid']
```